# how to add Privacy tab to settings charm?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

i want to add a privacy tab to settings charm " my app has been refused because of it " , but i want to open a page on my website when the user click privacy in settings charm .

I'm using javascript

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i've did it as shown below

```
            var vector = e.detail.e.request.applicationCommands;
            var cmd1 = new Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsCommand("privacy", "privacy", function () {
                window.open('http://www.dashsoft.com');
            });
            vector.append(cmd1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Note, that to pass certification you must **provide the link to your privacy policy in the submission form**

[image: Privacy Policy field in submission form]

Then you can also put a button on the Settings charm (as others described) or simply link to your privacy policy in an About page or similar.

Answer (score 3):

This might be solving your problem: Don't fail to mark this as an answer.

In default.html

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'privacy', width:'narrow'}">
        <div class="win-ui-dark win-header">
            <button type="button" onclick="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.show()" class="win-backbutton"></button>
            <div class="win-label">Privacy Policy</div>
        </div>
        <div class="win-content win-settings-section">
            <script type="text/javascript">
window.open("your-privacy-link");
</script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In JavaScript

```
WinJS.Application.onsettings = function (e) {
        e.detail.applicationcommands = {
            "privacy": {
                title: "Privacy Policy",
            }
        };
        WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(e);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than opening a browser window which would take the user out of your app experience I would suggest using an iframe instead.  In your scenario you would navigate to a local privacy page (ie: /pages/privacy/privacy.html).  Inside of privacy.html you have a simple div tag with an iframe in it with it's src pointing to your privacy page.

Technically you only need a privacy policy in place if your app requested Internet Access capabilities.  My advice is to get in the habit of always having it.

- Privacy policy is a huge reason for app certification failures.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh921583.aspx

Comment: Yup , i did it in the way you mentioned but after i tried Bing App in Windows 8 i found that they are opening a web page

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an app settings to your app. You can refer to this [MSDN QuickStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780611.aspx) to do so.

For example:

```
WinJS.Application.onsettings = function (e) {
        e.detail.applicationcommands = {
            "defaultsDiv": { href: "DefaultsUI.html", title: "Defaults"},
            "helpDiv": { href: "HelpUI.html", title: "Help"}
        };
        WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(e);
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: i'm already did that but i want to lunch IE when user click on Privacy as shown above

Comment: You also have to set the URIs you want to include/exclude in your application in your package.appxmanifest in the Content URIs tab.

Comment: not i want to lunch for exmple www.microsoft.com when clicking on Privacy on Settings charm